# Papertrail and code access security

Tags: asp.net, security, papertrail-app

I am currently looking into papertrail and find it very interesting.
However my web application will be deployed to web servers that I don't control.
The problem is that I use this solution to send logs to papertrail:
http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/nlog-net-logging

And the way I see it I can't send logs on a website with medium trust level:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754779.aspx

Is this right?
Do you have any experience with using papertrail on medium trust sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right:

```
Medium (web_mediumtrust.config) - Specifies a medium level of code access security, which means that, in addition to High Trust Level restrictions, the ASP.NET application cannot do any of the following things by default:

 Access files outside the application directory.
 Access the registry.
 **Make network or Web service calls.**
```

As far as I can see is the papertrail logger using the network to do the logging to an external site/service.

Comment: Looks like the right answer, but I would like to see if someone has actual experience with it...

Comment: You can try it yourself, but I do not think that anyone has it working on a medium trust webserver. You should look for an other hosting company or change your specs/requirements.